# What the best mode to send a large json to server

Tags: javascript, c#, json, knockout.js, request

I have configured in my web.config with `maxrequestlength = 10MB`. But in my system there's a functionality of import a `.csv` and this `.csv` that my clients are import can have more than `10MB`. So, I need a mode with a good performance to send a large `json` (the `json` imported).

I thought of `zip` or send the `json` in parts. What is the best mode?

Is there other forms more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

Using the File APIs (https://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/file/dndfiles/), we can minimize the work to upload a large file. The technique is to slice the upload into multiple chunks, spawn an XHR for each portion, and put the file together on the server. This is similar to how GMail uploads large attachments so quickly. Such a technique could also be used to get around Google App Engine's 32MB http request limit.

```
function upload(blobOrFile) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '/server', true);
  xhr.onload = function(e) { ... };
  xhr.send(blobOrFile);
}

document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var blob = this.files[0];

  const BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 1024 * 1024; // 1MB chunk sizes.
  const SIZE = blob.size;

  var start = 0;
  var end = BYTES_PER_CHUNK;

  while(start < SIZE) {
    upload(blob.slice(start, end));

    start = end;
    end = start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK;
  }
}, false);

})();
```

What is not shown here is the code to reconstruct the file on the server.

P.S. Of cause functions like http://underscorejs.org/#zip can be used as well.

Comment: I will test this sample. Thanks